# Didn't find class "android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, androidx

I've migrated to AndroidX, and now, I've a problem on runtime.
The crash occurs on the MainActivity with NavigationView. All dependencies are androidx, and there's nothing related with support library.

I have already tried:
- Clean/Rebuild
- Invalidate Caches & Restart

```
Didn't find class "android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView" on path: DexPathList
```

Answer (score 1):

You must replace android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView to com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView regarding to [migrating](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) tutorial